# Reconfiguring MFA for SAML account

Tags: authentication, microsoft-office-365, saml

We use Office 365 SAML for authentication with NewRelic. I recently factory reset my phone and now don't have my Microsoft Authenticator account.

I am trying to figure out how to set this up again but am unable to locate the feature anywhere in either 365 settings or 365 admin. The SAML page thinks I already have this set up and I cannot see a way to re-activate.

Does anyone know where this option is?

Thanks